# Does cyclical monotonicity imply almost everywhere differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, convex-analysis

By a theorem due to Lebesgue, it is known that monotonicity of a univariate, real-valued function defined on an interval implies that it must be differentiable almost everywhere.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Can we conclude almost everywhere differentiability of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ given that it is $\textit{cyclically monotone}$?, i.e., for every $j\geq 2$ and every set of points $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_j\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $x_1=x_j$ that $$\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\langle x_{k+1}, f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)\rangle  \geq 0$$
where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the usual inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

It is easy to see that this property generalizes univariate monotonicity (increasing), hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem due to Rockafellar [sub](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2036628/is-there-an-intuition-for-cyclic-monotonicity) that says that given a cyclically monotone multifunction $\Gamma$, you can find a lower semicontinuous convex function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to (-\infty,\infty]$ such that the subgradient $\Gamma\subset\partial g$. In addition, if $\Gamma$ is a maximally cyclically monotone multifunction, then $\Gamma=\partial g$. If you define $\Gamma(x)=\{f(x)\}$, then you have a cyclically monotone multifunction. So you know that $f(x)\in \partial g(x)$ for every $x$.
If you now consider the interior $U$ of the effective domain of $g$, then $g$ is differentiable a.e in $U$, so $\partial g(x)=\{\nabla g(x)\}$ a.e. in $U$, which implies that $\nabla g=f$ a.e. in $U$. You can now use Alexandroff's theorem, to conclude that $f$ is differentiable a.e. in $U$. Take a look at these lecture notes [convex ana](http://giovannileoni.weebly.com/uploads/3/1/0/5/31054371/ca-lectures-2008-04-28.pdf). I don't know what happens outside of $U$.